# How to pass aggregation pipeline query (javascript file) to mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I need to export data from mongodb into csv file. The query is an aggregation pipeline and it is stored in js file. How do I pass this complex query as input to mongoexport.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the query in js file and load it. Check this out https://dasbotask.com/mongodb-export-mongoexport-using-aggregation/

Comment: would this have <name,value> pair for each column or would the field names would come as column header.

Comment: Yes, The code is tested and verified, I am using it in my regular work for exporting mongodb documents in .csv file by using custom large aggregation query. You have to tailor made for your scenario, I just shown you the way It can be achieved.

Comment: moreover, mongoexport will not help, -q parameter of mongoexport is taking small queries not aggregation, you can roam for other solutions but, ultimately you have to land in a javascript and export it in a .csv file.